# Iphone UITabBar with Segmented Control

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iphone app I have to place tab bar at the bottom of the application and whenever each tab bar item is clicked more buttons should be poped-up and by clicking those buttons new view should be opened.

I want to know if it is possible through some way that tab bar like structure pop-up(don't want to use actionsheet because it covers the current view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `UIBarButtonItems` to the toolbar's view, and set the selector on them to be the code that adds new views.